# Getting absolute path in Angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Hey guys first time poster long time lurker :) I need some help with and angular app I am "trying" to build. The main thing i need help with is getting the absolute path of the app regardless of the working directory tree (if I am even saying that right). I am new to angularjs which is why I am coming to the pros.

Here is a code snippet that I think it is going to need to go in.

```
function MainCtrl(user, auth) {
  var self = this;

  function handleRequest(res) {
    var token = res.data ? res.data.token : null;
    if(token) { console.log('JWT:', token); }
    self.message = res.data.message;
  }

  self.login = function() {
    user.login(self.username, self.password)
      .then(handleRequest, handleRequest)
  }

  self.logout = function() {
    auth.logout && auth.logout()
  }
  self.isAuthed = function() {
    return auth.isAuthed ? auth.isAuthed() : false
  }
}

angular.module('app', [])
.factory('authInterceptor', authInterceptor)
.service('user', userService)
.service('auth', authService)
.constant('API', 'http://appsdev.tempportal.com/api')
.config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
})
.controller('Main', MainCtrl)
})();
```

as you can see: *.constant('API', 'http://appsdev.tempportal.com/api')* is where I have it now. But that is going to get moved to the live server once finished. But the main problem is that in a year it will most likely get moved to a new server with a new domain name.

So I need someway to get the current URL so that I don't have to go in and change the code to the new URL. I don't know where I will be in a year, or 3 months for that matter, so I want them to not have to worry about changing the URL every time they move the server.

I have seen $location in angular but I haven't really used it yet. What can I do?

Hope I have provided you with enough info. Let me know if you want more of the code or not. Thanks in advance for any help. And I look forward to picking more of your brains in the future. :)

UA

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a build process using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/):

This way, you can detect whether or not you are in testing mode or production mode.

Usually this is done by running `Grunt Debug` or `Grunt Production` in the command line when you want to build a project.

There are many ways to go about doing this, but here is an oversimplified example. Normally you would set up a [Custom Task](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#custom-tasks) to do this:

Example:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  concat: {
    options: {
      // Task-level options may go here, overriding task defaults.
    },
    foo: {
      options: {
        // "foo" target options may go here, overriding task-level options.
        if(production){
             app.serverPath = "http://appsdev.tempportal.com/api";
        }
        else{ 
             app.serverPath = "http://appsdev.tempportal.com/api"; 
        }
       },
    },
    bar: {
      // No options specified; this target will use task-level options.
    },
  },
});

grunt.registerTask('dev', ['uglify']);
grunt.registerTask('production', ['minify']);
```

And then in your `MainCtrl`:

```
    angular.module('app', [])
.factory('authInterceptor', authInterceptor)
.service('user', userService)
.service('auth', authService)
.constant('API', app.serverPath)
.config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
})
.controller('Main', MainCtrl)
})();
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of doing is to consolidate all of your addresses into grunt build paths (or updating the gruntfile as needed). A grunt custom task could be able to take in whatever URL you input into the command line and assign that throughout your app all at once. grunt.registerTask('foo', 'My "foo" task.', function(bar) {
  app.serverPath = bar;
});

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! In the end I can change the temp server link to the live link address. The thing is that they tend to move their servers around as policies change internally with the company ( I know, crazy right). So the problem will be when they move the server from appsdev.tempportal.com to one with a new name like pccapp.com I need to grab that absolute path kinda like what you have now maybe " .constant('API', app.serverPath/ecar/api). The base domain before /ecar/api will change about 3 times a year. So i just need to grab that root domain and apply it before /ecar.

Comment: The address are not known yet. They wont know the address until they pick it a year later when they move it. Once they move it they domain name will change. I figured there would be a way in angular to get the absolute path that the server is on and then put it before the folder names.

Comment: You could use regex and store the values, but I'm not seeing how that would help much if the domain is changing anyway.